# How to get response with this request in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

Hi I have a request as so

```
GET https://dropezy.goadda.in/master/v1/id/products/search?q=buah&storeId=619e02f0f580166d48277fc0&sortBy=relevance HTTP/2.0
accept: application/json
enro-api-key: rhcvwcdd-7aza-zvv7qskyu-4b8jm8kwppkf
cache-control: max-age=31536000
store-id: 619e02f0f580166d48277fc0
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; sdk_gphone_x86 Build/RSR1.201013.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Mobile Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
origin: https://www.dropezy.com
x-requested-with: com.enroco.dropezy
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
referer: https://www.dropezy.com/id/search/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 0
```

When I tried using request in python it returns message not found
This is my current code

```
url = 'https://dropezy.goadda.in/master/v1/id/products/search?q=buah&storeId=619e02f0f580166d48277fc0&sortBy=relevance HTTP/2.0'
accept='application/json'

jsonData = requests.post(url, accept).json()
```

Can somebody help? How to insert the other components such as user-agent, enro-api-key into requests?

Comment: That URL doesn't require any special headers - not even a User-Agent. So just do a GET, check the status code and extract the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two requests aren't the same. The first is a `GET` request, but the second is a `POST`.

Use `requests.get` to make a `GET` request.

If you need to supply headers in a request, yes, you can do that: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers.

Generally, the docs for Requests are quite good: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/